# How to convert date and from GMT to IST in Node js

Tags: node.js, string, date, timezone

I have a string

```
str = "Tue, 10 Feb 2022 10:17:16 GMT"
```

I wanted to convert it into IST(Indian Standard Time) with similar format i.e., it should have simlar day, date, time. like this

```
str = "Tue, 10 Feb 2022 09:17:16 IST"
```

How to do it?

Comment: IST is not 1 hour earlier than GMT. It is 5.5 hours earlier. So the IST string must be `Tue, 10 Feb 2022 15:47:16 IST`

Comment: Have you tried using Date? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)